# User Notification Center get Authorization Options Swift 3/4 ios10/11

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

For iOS lower than 10 we used to have the property to get the types (.alert, .badge etc) of notifications User allowed. We used this code:

`UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types`

But it's now deprecated.

**Question:**

How can we do the same but using `UNUserNotificationCenter` for ios10/11?
Is there an equivalent method?

Consider: the deprecated way still works but we never know if one day Apple will take it down.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still get the notification settings by:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in

    if settings.alertSetting == .enabled {
        //alert is enabled
    }

}
```

As it's mentioned in [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings/1648396-alertsetting)

> When the value of this property is UNNotificationSetting.enabled, the
>   app is authorized to display alerts.

Comment: thanks:)) was able to figure it out just before you answered :))